# error: passing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer

Tags: c, compiler-errors, byte, cs50

```
// TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
uint8_t buffer[HEADER_SIZE];
uint8_t *header;
fread(buffer, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);
header = malloc(HEADER_SIZE + 1);
buffer[HEADER_SIZE] = '\0';
strcpy(header, buffer);
```

When I try to copy buffer into header, it tells me "ERROR: passing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Werror,-Wpointer-sign]" I think what it's trying to say is that i'm treating a byte like a string. But I'm really not sure how to treat a byte any differently in this scenario.

Comment: Please add all your includes and defines for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Either declare `buffer` and `header` as `char[]` or cast them to `char *` when passing to `strcpy()`.

Comment: Placing a `nul` terminator at the end suggests you want to treat the array as a C string. But the note `// TODO: Copy header from input file to output file` suggests that you should be using `memcpy()` not `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` expects pointers to `char` for both arguments, `char` is a different type from `unsigned char` even on platforms where `char` is unsigned by default. You can just cast both arguments as `(char *)` to silence the warning.

Note however that there is a more pressing problem: `buffer` is defined with a length of `HEADER_SIZE` and you indeed read `HEADER_SIZE` bytes into it, but you invoke undefined behavior when you set the null terminator in order to call `strcpy`: `buffer[HEADER_SIZE] = '\0';` writes the `'\0'` beyond the end of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
uint8_t buffer[HEADER_SIZE + 1];
uint8_t *header;
fread(buffer, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);
header = malloc(HEADER_SIZE + 1);
buffer[HEADER_SIZE] = '\0';
strcpy((char *)header, (const char *)buffer);
```

Another question is why use `uint8_t` for `header` which you clearly intend to use as a string?

As suggested by *@JohnBollinger*, you can construct the string a bit more cleanly (without casts) this way:

```
uint8_t buffer[HEADER_SIZE];
fread(buffer, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);
char *header = malloc(HEADER_SIZE + 1);
memcpy(header, buffer, HEADER_SIZE);
header[HEADER_SIZE] = '\0';
```

Or even simpler:

```
char buffer[HEADER_SIZE];
fread(buffer, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);
char *header = strndup(buffer, HEADER_SIZE);
```

Or as suggested by @user3386109, without a local buffer:

```
char *header = calloc(sizeof(*header), HEADER_SIZE + 1);
fread(header, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);
```

Comment: Alternatively, they could use `memcpy()` in place of `strcpy()`, and add the terminator to `header` instead of to `buffer`.  That would also remove the need for the casts, and overall makes a bit more sense to me.  It might even be faster.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: good point. answer amended.

Comment: To make it even simpler, get rid of the `buffer` altogether. Two lines: `uint8_t *header = malloc(...);` and `fread(header, ...);` will do, because `fread` takes a `void *` and therefore doesn't care about the type used for `header`.

Comment: @user3386109: yes, one more alternative...

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this code fragment is unclear.

Do you really need `buffer[]` if you know the number of bytes to be loaded? You could simply use a buffer `malloc()`'d before the read. Do you *need* two copies of the bytes?

Using `uint8_t` suggests *binary* data (not necessarily limited to ASCII characters), so attempting to terminate with a `'\0'` (suggesting a *"string"*) is confusing to the reader. Could the buffer of "unsigned bytes" contain another byte that is `'\0'`?

`uint8_t buffer[HEADER_SIZE];` allocates `HEADER_SIZE` bytes, therefore `buffer[HEADER_SIZE] = '\0';` writes beyond the end of the local array and is *undefined*.

Returned values from system calls to `malloc()` and `fread()` **must** be checked!

Here's a version that fixes these issues:

```
// TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
uint8_t *header = malloc( HEADER_SIZE );
if( header == NULL )
    // handle allocation failure
if( fread( header, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input ) != HEADER_SIZE )
    // handle bad read of expected bytes

// do stuff and eventually...
free( header ); // not to be forgotten.
```

Answer (score -1):

This error indicates that you try to compile `C` code using `C++` compiler which is not correct.

1. GCC use `-xc` option yo force compilation as **C** source
2. Microsoft compilers `/TC` option.

C++ does not allow implicit pointer conversions and it requires explicit casts.

```
strcpy((char *)header, (char *)buffer);
```

---

## EDIT:

as you set `-Wpointer-sign` option you need to use casts to prevent warnings. `-Werror` forces treating warnings as errors.